# Light bulb Flickering In Wall Socket but not plugged in Lamp

Tags: lighting, led, light-bulb

In my living room.  When I screw in a light bulb with 5000k in a preinstalled wall socket, then turn on the light, it flickers on and off indefinitely.

When I screw it into a lamp I plugged into an outlet, it works just fine.

The prior bulb that worked in the wall socket, has 2700k.

Everything else seems to be the same.

Socket says "listed 36HP 250V 660W"

Comment: What type of bulb? LED bulbs will flicker if on a dimer turned down too low for them to maintain the needed voltage, and sometimes can interact with each other under low voltage.

Comment: Just found out they are non dimmable, and apparently need to be dimmable - from prop manager.  Thanks!

Comment: @keshlam, please make an answer out of that so we can close this!

Comment: I was gonna ask if the wall switch was a dimmer...